# Explain the ' notation in F#

Tags: f#

I'm learning F#, when I type any code in Visual Studio and run them on *F# Interactive* it shows me things like

```
val foo : x:'a -> 'a
```

I imagine this mean that `foo` is a function that receive a paramater `x` of a type, and returns a value of same x's type.

But **What does that `'` mean?** Many functions show such thing on intellisense too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The single quote mark (`'`) means that the type of that parameter is generic.  It can be inferred, like the example you gave, or it can be explicitly applied.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233215.aspx) under Implicitly Generic Constructs for more information.

Answer (score 17):

`'a`  represents a type variable, in other words a type that is not determined yet (and doesn't have to be determined yet).

Note that this is different than `a'`, which is a regular variable whose name is two characters: *a* and *'*. Contrary to other languages like C#, the single quote is a permitted character in F# variable names, except as the first character in the name to disambiguate from type variables above.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for when I searched for "single quote meaning in F#".

Comment: Where is the `a'` notation useful?