# Purpose of tick (apostrophe) in F# value names?

Tags: f#

I'm going through a tutorial on Function Composition, and I keep seeing the **'** operator used at the end of a value declaration.

I know that it means a generic when it precedes a parameter, but what does it mean when you see it like:

```
let add x y = x + y
let myFunc' = add 10
```

The only thing I can see is that the *'* is just another character in the identifier. Is that right? Because if I use that same example, using *myFunc* gives a not defined error, where *myFunc'* does resolve.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's just another character in the identifier.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912115/explain-the-notation-in-f/17912578#17912578.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, as @Lee pointed, `'` is a valid identifier.

Though, **the purpose** of `'` at the end of identifiers generally **is to denote the value as  something related or similar to the value named without the ending `'`**. This is [borrowed from mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29#Use_in_mathematics.2C_statistics.2C_and_science), F# being a functional language, for denoting something as being *prime* since *A* is pronounced `aye` where *A'* is `aye-prime`.

Comment: Story time: I sometimes also use it (and have seen other people use it like that from time to time) to denote recursive nested function, so that top-level function may be called `insert`, while inner one would be `let rec insert'`, for a lack of better naming :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, ' is a valid identifier character, although it cannot be the first one. The structure of identifiers is defined in the [specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818774):

**3.4 Identifiers and Keywords**

> ident-text = ident-start-char ident-char*
>
> ident-char =   letter-char   | digit-char   | connecting-char   |
>   combining-char   | formatting-char   | '   | _